# REGEX: delete all words not starting with specific character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text like this:

```
§abc §def word1 word2 word3 word4

§ghi §jkl §mno word5 §pqr word6 word7
```

I want to keep all the words starting with "`§`" (`§abc`, `§def`, etc) and delete the others (`word1`, `word2`, etc). I also want to preserve rows and leave a single space between words, so that the output text would be like this:

```
§abc §def

§ghi §jkl §mno §pqr
```

I've already tried to find an answer but nothing worked for me Thanks!

REAL CASE EXAMPLE:

`What is a §text? The §words that make up the main part of a book, magazine, §newspaper, Web site, etc.`

EXPECTED RESULT:

`§text §words §newspaper`

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Your problem can be solved using, for example, negative lookbehinds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. Could you tell me how to write the expression using negative lookbehinds? I'm going to use it in Notepad++

Comment: If you'll google for what neg. lookbehinds are  - it will be pretty obvious to you how to write such an expression. Shortly - it should be something like word boundary + negative lookbehind of § symbol + one or more \w character.

Comment: how about simply replacing `[\w]+` by nothing and checking "find only words"? Disclaimer: I don't use notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Is this simple way working for you:

Find what: `\w+` (a space followed by word characters)
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Edit according to comment:

Find what: `\b(?<!§)\w+`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

**new edit:**

Find what: `\b(?<!§)[^§]+`
Replace with:  (one space)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Your expression finds all the words and leaves symbols. I have to delete everyting except the words beginning with §.

Comment: I've tried this: `(?<!\w)§\w+` and it finds all the words beginning with § but I need the opposite (find and replace with nothing all the words and strings **not** beginning with §)

Comment: yes thanks it seems to work! Now I have all the unwanted text selected but there are still symbol characters (punctuation, brackets, ect) I want to delete that aren't selected.

Comment: @rescog: Please, edit your question to add a real case of original text and expected result.

Comment: Real case: `What is a §text? The §words that make up the main part of a book, magazine, §newspaper, Web site, etc.` Expected result: `§text §words §newspaper`

Comment: this is almost perfect! just one more thing: is it possible to mantain carriage returns?